# Full Screen Flash Video on One Screen + Other Stuff on the Other?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, video, flash, youtube

I'm running Windows 7 plus Firefox on a dual monitor setup.  When I try to watch Flash video (ESPN3, southparkstudios.com, YouTube, etc.) in full screen in one Firefox window plus browse the Web in another window, on my other screen, clicking on the Web browsing screen brings the Flash window out of full screen.  Apparently these sites were not designed for this kind of dual monitor use.  Is there any decent workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>With Adobe Flash, this is not possible.</s> Flash now supports dual monitor use & you can go full screen on one monitor and not have it come out of full screen on the other screen..

An alternative is to use the "pop-out" feature(by which I mean clicking on the Popout link creates a new window) and then extend the window throughout the monitor. This is what I do.

Comment: what is the "pop out" feature?

Comment: ah right click on the video, and you get it. thanks. that's works

Comment: @RoboShop updated